# ServiceStack how to use MaxLoginAttempts feature

Tags: c#, servicestack

I tried to add the MaxLoginAttempts feature in my ServiceStack project. But it is still allowing login attempts after 5 unsuccessful login attempts. I'm not sure to know what is missing in my code.

AppHost.cs :

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

    Routes
        .Add<Hello>("/hello")
        .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name*}");

    var appSettings = new AppSettings();

    //Enable a custom authentication
    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
        new IAuthProvider[] {
            new CustomAuthProvider(appSettings),
        })
    {
        MaxLoginAttempts = 5
    });
}
```

CustomAuthProvider.cs

```
public CustomAuthProvider(AppSettings appSettings) : base(appSettings) {}

public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
{
    // authentication logic
    if (userName.Equals("username") && password.Equals("password"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
{
    //Saving the session!
    return base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MaxLoginAttempts` gets validated when you [validate the Username/Password against the AuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/fcd639d3a2c13232b9dc7ac15333b829f7b9412d/src/ServiceStack/Auth/CredentialsAuthProvider.cs#L60):

```
public virtual bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
{
    var authRepo = GetUserAuthRepository(authService.Request);
    using (authRepo as IDisposable)
    {
        var session = authService.GetSession();
        if (authRepo.TryAuthenticate(userName, password, out var userAuth))
        {
            if (IsAccountLocked(authRepo, userAuth))
                throw new AuthenticationException(ErrorMessages.UserAccountLocked.Localize(authService.Request));

            session.PopulateSession(userAuth, authRepo);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Since you're overriding `TryAuthenticate()` and not using an Auth Repository you're going to have to validate it yourself where you'll need to maintain a `InvalidLoginAttempts` counter wherever you're persisting the User Info.

If it helps this is what all Auth Repositories use to [validate invalid password attempts](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/8b4ed107ab72d8e4a1b878ecb8c10feee6a34ca1/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UserAuth.cs#L335):

```
public static void RecordInvalidLoginAttempt(this IUserAuthRepository repo, IUserAuth userAuth)
{
    var feature = HostContext.GetPlugin<AuthFeature>();
    if (feature?.MaxLoginAttempts == null) return;

    userAuth.InvalidLoginAttempts += 1;
    userAuth.LastLoginAttempt = userAuth.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    if (userAuth.InvalidLoginAttempts >= feature.MaxLoginAttempts.Value)
    {
        userAuth.LockedDate = userAuth.LastLoginAttempt;
    }
    repo.SaveUserAuth(userAuth);
}
```

---

Note: the recommend way to set Camel Case is to use:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { UseCamelCase = true });
```

For all other Serialization customization you should use [JsConfig.Init()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#global-default-json-configuration), e.g:

```
JsConfig.Init(new Config {
    DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601,
    AlwaysUseUtc = true,
    TextCase = TextCase.CamelCase,
    ExcludeDefaultValues = true,                
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I will take this in consideration.